# How to create my own prefix for my plugins?

Tags: gimp, gimpfu

Gimp says this when it fails to install my python plug-in:

```
Querying plug-in: '/home/jorge/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/enumerategrid.py'
GIMP-Error: Plug-In "enumerategrid.py"
(/home/jorge/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/enumerategrid.py)
attempted to install procedure "python-fu-enumerategrid-plugin" in the invalid menu location "<Desarrollo de juegos>/rejillas/Enumerar".
Use either "<Image>", "<Layers>", "<Channels>", "<Vectors>", "<Colormap>", "<Brushes>", "<Dynamics>", "<Gradients>", "<Palettes>", "<Patterns>", "<ToolPresets>", "<Fonts>" or "<Buffers>".
```

Cool. But, how do you create a new prefix for your own plug-ins? It is even possible?

### EDIT

seems that using the `<Image>` prefix makes the menu `Desarrollo de juegos` appears on Gimp's menu, which is the thing I want. That's the intended behavior of `<Image>` prefix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the original question:

No, it is not possible to come up with other prefixes like these - they are hardcoded into GIMP Python --
But you can create a plug-in that takes *no* such prefix. If youd'use just:
`"Desarrollo de juegos/rejillas/Enumerar"` (without the `<...>`) a new
"Desarrollo de juegos/" menu would appear on your window.

Using the prefixes, however, not only can make the plug-in show-up in a specialized
sub menu (if you use `<Gradients>` for example, it will show up in the context menu
in the Gradient list dokcable dialog) - but makes GIMP try to automatically insert
the starting parameter(s)  for your plug-in.

So, a plug-in with the `<Image>` prefix which takes an image as first parameter and a drawable as second parameter, will automatically receive the current active image and active drawable (usually a layer) as the first two parameters. The plug-in dialog  won't generate an entry for those 2 parameters. Similarly, a plug-in in `<Gradients>` that features a `pf_gradient` first parameter, will have be called with the gradient on which the user right-clicked to get the gradient context-menu.